# Getting error "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined" when using tough-cookie cookie jar through an Express session

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, fetch

I am making an API using Express on NodeJS for a student web service. It requires to log in and in the process it stores session and other cookies to authenticate the process.

I am using the Express session with my two routes. For the `login` route, I create a cookie jar using `tough.CookieJar()` for my fetch (node-fetch with fetch-cookie) requests. Before making the requests, I store the cookie jar object into `req.session.cookieJar = cookieJar`. When I try to access `req.session.cookieJar` in my other route, `email`, (which requires login cookies to access the data), it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

I am not sure why this is and I am wondering how I could fix this. I also don't mind other possible solutions to what I am trying to accomplish.

Code:

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const session = require('express-session')
const port = 3000

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use('/email', require('./email'))
app.use('/login', require('./login'))

app.listen(port)
```

`login.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')
const tough = require('tough-cookie')
const nodeFetch = require('node-fetch')

const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar()
const fetch = require('fetch-cookie/node-fetch')(nodeFetch, cookieJar)
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    req.session.cookieJar = cookieJar
    // fetch request
})

module.exports = router
```

`email.js`

```js
const express = require('express')
const nodeFetch = require('node-fetch')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const fetch = require('fetch-cookie/node-fetch')(nodeFetch, req.session.cookieJar) // Error is given here
    // fetch request 
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I believe I didn't use Express session and put the cookieJar in a separate file and then exported it in the file. For each route, I just called the file like `const cookieJar = require('./cookie.js')`. Hope this works.